# Namerror when trying to use def

Tags: python, function

I keep getting "NameError: name 'get_length' is not defined". What's wrong with my code?

```
def get_length_get_width_get_depth(ask_for_length,ask_for_width,ask_for_depth):

    "Ask the user for the object's length,width, and depth"

    length = raw_input(ask_for_length)
    width = raw_input(ask_for_width)
    depth = raw_input(ask_for_depth)

    return  length,width,depth

length,width,depth = get_length, get_width, get_depth("What is the length of the object?","What is the depth?", "What is the width?")

print"\nThe object's length,width, and depth is %s,%s, and %s, respectively" % (length,width,depth)
```

Comment: Not sure of the point of this function.  Usually, a function is used to abstract away duplicate code or to create a useful abstraction for understanding your code.  This function just serves to obfuscate things.  Try this: first define a simple ask_question function, then define another function that asks the three questions you'll be asking a lot, which should your ask_question function.  You'll find this much more comprehensible, modifiable, extendable, and usable in your code base.

Comment: I'd rename the method to `get_dimensions` to keep your code readable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have no defined `get_length` method, just `get_length_get_width_get_depth`

try

```
length,width,depth = get_length_get_width_get_depth("What is the length of the object?","What is the depth?", "What is the width?")
```

Also to fix typos and unnecessary code in your question, take a look at this complete sample

```
def get_length_get_width_get_depth(ask_for_length,ask_for_width,ask_for_depth):

    "Ask the user for the object's length,width, and depth"

    length = raw_input(ask_for_length)
    width = raw_input(ask_for_width)
    depth = raw_input(ask_for_depth)

    return  length,width,depth

response = get_length_get_width_get_depth("What is the length of the object?",
                                          "What is the depth?",
                                          "What is the width?")

print "\nThe object's length,width, and depth is %s,%s, and %s, respectively" %\
        response
```

Answer (score 1):

`length,width,depth = get_length_get_width_get_depth("What is the length of the object?","What is the depth?", "What is the width?")`

this is probably what you are looking for.